# Regex in an API.ai entity

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is it possible to detect an entity using a regex? 
For example, I want a number starting with '91xxxxxxx' to be mapped with an entity named EmployeeID. So if the user says something like - "Please pull out today's report for 91xxxxxxx", I should be able to map the number to the EmployeeID entity.

Comment: what you want to achieve with regular expression ? regex is only to identify the pattern in a string.

Comment: @AlokVishwakarma - I want to identify a pattern in the user's input using a regex, and map that matched pattern as an entity.

Comment: fine mean you are trying to find the string having 91XXXXX this kind of number, so we can move ahead with regular expression. do want me to design a grammar for matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [multiple requests about this on the API.AI forum](https://discuss.api.ai/search?q=regex). Unfortunately, presently the answer to your question is No.

The [current suggestion](https://discuss.api.ai/t/is-there-a-way-to-detect-pattern-and-assign-it-to-entity/244/5) is to use the @sys.any wildcard and implement the regex functionality in your business logic.

Comment: I did look at the forums earlier and saw that this was apparently on their to-do list (around August last year, from what I read). Was wondering if there was any info about whether it has been implemented or not? Will try the @sys.any suggestion though. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible now?